# ASTVisitor Class Definition node

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been using the ASTVisitor class in Eclipse in order to take data at Method Declaration and Method Invocation nodes.  I now also want to take data at Class Declaration nodes, but I can't find anything in the API for the ASTVisitor that would allow me to do this.  Am I missing something?  What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `ClassDeclaration` you should look for [TypeDeclaration](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/TypeDeclaration.html) objects because:

> A type declaration is the union of a class declaration and an
>   interface declaration.

Once you found it you just have to use [isInterface()](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FTypeDeclaration.html&anchor=isInterface%28%29) method and if it returns false then it is  `ClassDeclaration`.

Answer (score 0):

The node "Class Declaration" that you are interested in is actually the TypeDeclaration, the node from which to take in the information that you need. For example:

- The list of modifiers ('public', etc.) allows you to figure out which and how many modifiers (node.modifiers ())
- The type of the super class, if it exists (node.getSuperclassType ())
- All the declarations of the methods
- etc

However, these are details that you need to build from a TypeDeclaration

However, both methods are inherited TypeDeclaration that can help you get all the info that you need to traverse the tree in a top-down approach.